# Transfer data between android devices

Tags: android

I have created an android app and would like to enable users to transfer data (e.g. over TCP). Both have my app installed. Is there any framework or guide how to use bluetooth and/or w-lan to get a good user experience? How do they initiate the connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned how to use Bluetooth on Android by [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) link, analysing the source code of the example.
About sending information through TCP/IP, use normal Java for that (Sockets, for example). The only extra you could put it is to send an Intent to activate Wireless if was not activated yet.