# How to transfer sqlite3 database between two Android devices using Socket?

Tags: android, sockets, sqlite, android-wifi, data-transfer

I have read this [Bluetooth Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837463/transfer-data-between-android-devices) post, and this [Transfer file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650690/transfer-a-file-between-android-devices) post.And I have two real android devices ,not AVDs, my 
intent is to set IP address and port in one device which acts as a Client while the other acts as a Server.

They are using WIFI,and I have connected both of them to  PC respectively.Get into adb shell ,and ping each other.It works.
I have written client code like this:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.142",8888);

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];

        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(in.available()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        in.read(buffer);

        String msg = new String(buffer);

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and the Server:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);
        while(true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();

            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

            String msg = "Hello Android!";

            out.write(msg.getBytes());

            client.close();
        }
```

I have add this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to manifest.

But no response. I have two questions:

1.Why there is no response in my client?

2.How to handle with sqlite3 database ,there must be something different with ordinary text files,but what is the difference?

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be unwise to transfer a sqlite3 .db between devices that may be differing make/model/manufacturer/etc. Rather, you should dump the schema and content of database to csv or sql and transfer that. You may want to compress the file too before transfer.

As for networking with Android. If you're using an AVD (emulator) then you're going to find it impossible or near impossible. Your proxy also plays a role in networking so you need to be warey of what it allows, how it's currently configured, and how it behaves (bugs, quirks, features). You should use a tool such as wireshark to inspect network comms and make sure that your App is even sending something out before worrying whether that something gets recieved.

Comment: Your sugguestion is very helpful.First dump then transfer.But I've got a lot of troubles when dump the sqlite3 database in my project.Because I want to excute command in my program,not in adb shell manually.I don't want to root my device in order to get the privilege.The problem now is how to acheive the root privilege in my app.

Comment: Rooting to solve a problem = very bad solution. If the sender's codebase knows about the schema, use that knowledge to communicate schema to recipient. The db's content can be extracted via SELECT queries. If the recipient doesn't have code that already knows about the schema, then column names aren't really going to be so important anyways and you can simply rely on the column indexing to reference columns.

Comment: Indeed ,i have ran into a wrong direction.I think it will be easier to transfer the whole sqlite3 db.And i did not even think  much about what info the other end need.So ,i've got to think more about it.Thank you very very much .